# WordPress enqueue - what's the connection between script name and script file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

When enqueue-ing a jQuery containing javascript script into the function.php file, what is the connection between the **script name** and the **file** containing the jQuery script? Is the script name just a made up name or does it take from the file name or the script contained within the referenced file? Thanks for the help.

ex:

```
function exp_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script_file.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'exp_script' );
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a unique name that refers to the script. There are lots of scripts included via `wp_enqueue_script` handle so the each script must have unique name that refers to that script. It also helps wordpress to find and log the issues.

$handle :
(string) (Required) Name of the script. Should be unique.

Reference : [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Answer (score 0):

No , there is no relation between these two names , it is just a handler name. But if you use handles name a like like to file name, it's easy to relate them.

Comment: So there's nothing within the script file, a function, etc. that has the same name as the script name?

Comment: your file can have numerous function and with any name. It doesn't matter also.